# Avatar command give error when the user is a role discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, avatar

I am making an avatar command, the command works but I can't figure out a way on how to give an error if the member is a role or just if the member is not a member. Thanks.

My Code :

```
@client.command(aliases=["av","useravatar","usericon","userav","icon"])
async def avatar(ctx, *,  avamember : discord.Member=None):
  try:
    if avamember == None:
      Author = ctx.author
      userAvatarUrl = Author.avatar_url
      stringUrl = str(userAvatarUrl)

      png = stringUrl.replace("webp","png")
      jpg = stringUrl.replace("webp","jpg")

      embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{Author}'s avatar.",
      description = f"**Links :** \n[Default]({userAvatarUrl}) \n[PNG]({png}) \n[JPG]({jpg})",
      color = 0xf461ff)

      embed.set_image(url=userAvatarUrl)
 
      now = datetime.now()
      current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

      embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by  {ctx.author} at {current_time}")
      await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
    else:
      userAvatarUrl = avamember.avatar_url
      stringUrl = str(userAvatarUrl)
      png = stringUrl.replace("webp","png")
      jpg = stringUrl.replace("webp","jpg")

      embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{avamember}'s avatar.",
      description = f"**Links :** \n[Default]({userAvatarUrl}) \n[PNG]({png}) \n[JPG]({jpg})",
      color = 0xf461ff)

      embed.set_image(url=userAvatarUrl)

      now = datetime.now()
      current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

      embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by  {ctx.author} at {current_time}")
      await ctx.reply(embed=embed,mention_author=False)
  except:
    embed = discord.Embed(title = f"ERROR!",
    description = f"An error acurred, please try again.",
    color = 0xf461ff)

    embed.set_image(url=userAvatarUrl)

    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

    embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by  {ctx.author} at {current_time}")
    await ctx.reply(embed=embed,mention_author=False)
```

The error I get :

Ignoring exception in command avatar:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 855, in invoke
await self.prepare(ctx)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 789, in prepare
await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 706, in _parse_arguments
kwargs[name] = await self.transform(ctx, param)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 552, in transform
return await self.do_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 505, in do_conversion
return await self._actual_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 451, in _actual_conversion
ret = await instance.convert(ctx, argument)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/converter.py", line 195, in convert
raise MemberNotFound(argument)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MemberNotFound: Member "<@&903148254051577859>" not found.

Comment: Make sure thats the right role id

Answer (score 0):

You can do an `if` statement that will check if the member is in the server or not.

```py
@client.command(aliases=["av","useravatar","usericon","userav","icon"])
async def avatar(ctx, *,  avamember : discord.Member=None):
  if avamember in ctx.guild:
    try:
        if avamember == None:
        Author = ctx.author
        userAvatarUrl = Author.avatar_url
        stringUrl = str(userAvatarUrl)

        png = stringUrl.replace("webp","png")
        jpg = stringUrl.replace("webp","jpg")

        embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{Author}'s avatar.",
        description = f"**Links :** \n[Default]({userAvatarUrl}) \n[PNG]({png}) \n[JPG]({jpg})",
        color = 0xf461ff)

        embed.set_image(url=userAvatarUrl)
    
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

        embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by  {ctx.author} at {current_time}")
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
        else:
        userAvatarUrl = avamember.avatar_url
        stringUrl = str(userAvatarUrl)
        png = stringUrl.replace("webp","png")
        jpg = stringUrl.replace("webp","jpg")

        embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{avamember}'s avatar.",
        description = f"**Links :** \n[Default]({userAvatarUrl}) \n[PNG]({png}) \n[JPG]({jpg})",
        color = 0xf461ff)

        embed.set_image(url=userAvatarUrl)

        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

        embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by  {ctx.author} at {current_time}")
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed,mention_author=False)
    except:
        embed = discord.Embed(title = f"ERROR!",
        description = f"An error acurred, please try again.",
        color = 0xf461ff)

        embed.set_image(url=userAvatarUrl)

        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

        embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by  {ctx.author} at {current_time}")
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed,mention_author=False)
  else:
      return await ctx.send("That member is not valid!")
```

Comment: When I put the if statement on the command, it just makes the command can only be used for the author of the command, and can't be used to check others avatar.

Comment: @MenIndo I edited my answer to make it work.